# append data to mysql table via submit button coded in php - not working

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I have a form in the woocommerce account side which *should* append new entries to a custom table I have added. However, I cannot figure out **WHY** when I press the submit button ... nothing happens. What I want is the submit button to either;

1) update the table with a new row IF user and sku dont exist

**OR**

2) change the address if user and sku already exist in the `wp_newaddress` table

Here is my code;

```
$userid = get_current_user_id();
echo "<p><h5>Change address:</h5>";

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<br><select name="sku">';
    echo '<option>-- Select product--</option>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  global $product;
    echo '<option value=' . $product->get_sku() . '>' . $product->get_sku() . ' </option>';
  endwhile;
echo '</select>';
echo '<br><input type="text" value="Insert new address here" id="address" size="40" />';
echo '<br><input type="submit" name="submit">';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $user = $_POST['$userid'];
  $sku = $_POST['sku'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];

  $con2 = mysqli_connect("IP","USER","PASS","wpdb");
  $updateaddress = "UPDATE wp_newaddress SET address='$address' WHERE user='$user' AND sku = '$sku'";
  $retval = mysqli_query($con2,$updateaddress);
  if($retval)
   {
       echo 'Data Updated';
   }else{
       echo 'Data Not Updated';
   }
   mysqli_close($con2);
   }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` with the method set to `post` and an `action` set? You can sometimes get away without `action` but forms may default to `get` rather than `post` if you don't specify.

Comment: I dont have it in a `<form>` , everything I have coded is in my comment above... how would I modify to be a `<form>` ? I figured giving items 'id' and then pressing submit would give every variable a response when submitted (I hope I am making sense).

Comment: Just add a `<form>` tag before the `<select>` and a closing `</form>` after the submit button. Right now without those tags you're probably sending all `$_GET`s rather than `$_POST`s.

Comment: @WebElaine OK - so I did that, and it did something ... but did not append to table. it just reverted to my shop page...

Comment: As my first comment noted, you need to set a form method and action - not just plain `<form>`.

Comment: So I tried this .... `echo '<form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">';` as per what I found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_update_php.htm) and it gave me a 404